# How to trigger Lambda after deleting Cognito user manually in the AWS console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, eventtrigger

After I delete an user in my Cognito user pool manually in the AWS Cognito console, I want to be able to delete my backend resources related to the user such as DynamoDB records and S3 bucket info.

The original plan is to set up a Cognito event trigger for delete user so that it will trigger a Lambda function after it detects the deletion of a Cognito user. Then the Lambda function will delete the backend resources.

However, I am not able to find a Cognito event trigger that seems to work. Any suggestions please? Is there a Cognito trigger for deleting user event at the console please? Please let me know. Thanks a lot in advance for your great help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Triggering a Lambda function upon deleting a user on AWS Cognito User Pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50876341/triggering-a-lambda-function-upon-deleting-a-user-on-aws-cognito-user-pool)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have actually read the post before and tried the Sync Trigger event and it does not seem to work. Set up the trigger as mentioned and delete an user. It is not triggered. Also last question was asked a few years ago, I am not sure if there is any update such that a Cognito trigger will be available for this situation. Please let me know.  Thanks.